# Split page into 4 sections with data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to split my page into 4 sections with data from database?
I'm displaying data from the database and they appear one by one on the table. And I want to split them into 4 parts and each of them will show another result from the database. In addition, I would like to make line in the middle, which will keep them separated. 
That's my code, to show results from DB: 
**EDIT:** Ok, I edited like u said, and now page is splitted on 2 section, but I got on them the same results. How to change this, that on the left side will be shown one record, and on the right side another.

```
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_wojewodztwo, company_powiat, company_miasto, company_name, telefon, company_nip, company_opis FROM test WHERE company_wojewodztwo = '$woj' AND company_powiat = '$pow' AND company_miasto = '$nazwa' ORDER BY RAND()");

         foreach ( $result as $k => $v )   {

    $c_name         = stripslashes($v->company_name);
    $c_opis         = stripslashes($v->company_opis);
    $c_mob_nr       = stripslashes($v->telefon);
    $c_nip      = stripslashes($v->company_nip);        
?>


<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_name; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_name; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_nip ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_nip ?></td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_mob_nr ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_mob_nr ?></td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_opis ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_opis ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        <?php if(count($result) != $k+1){ ?>
<p>___________________________________________________</p>
<?php } ?>  

    <?php

     }

?>
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo 'data 1'; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo 'data 2'; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo 'data 1'; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo 'data 2'; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I put styles inline, You try to put them in a css file.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code...

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_province, company_district, company_city, company_name, telefon, company_nip, company_opis FROM test WHERE company_province = '$woj' AND company_district = '$pow' AND company_city = '$nazwa' ORDER BY RAND()");

    foreach ( $result as $k => $v )   {

    $c_name         = stripslashes($v['company_name']);
    $c_opis         = stripslashes($v['company_opis']);
    $c_mob_nr       = stripslashes($v['telefon']);
    $c_nip      = stripslashes($v['company_nip']);        
?>
        <div class="parent">
        <table>
        <tr><th><p><b> Name: </b></th><td>
        <?php echo $c_name;?></p></td></tr>

        <tr><th><p><b> NIP: </b></th><td>
         <?php echo $c_nip;?></p></td></tr>

        <tr><th><b> Number tel: </b></th><td>
        <?php echo '+48 '.$c_mob_nr;?><br></td></tr>

        <tr><th><b> Opis Firmy: </b></th><td>
<span class="more"> <?php echo $c_opis;?></span></td></tr> 
</table>
<?php if(count($result) != $k+1){ ?>
<p>___________________________________________________</p>
<?php } ?>
        </div>

<?php
 }
?>
```